# Using ON CASCADE CONSTRAINT for oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle11g

I would like to do ON Update Cascade but otacle does not support it. Is there anyways to do that

```
    create table parentTable
    (
      Username varchar2 (50) primary key,
      password varchar2 (50)
   );

   create table childTable
   (
      ID varchar2 (10),
     Name varchar2 (50),
     email_address varchar2 (50) references parentTable (Username)
   );
```

Comment: do you mean foreign key?

Comment: thanks for reply yup.

Answer (score 0):

I see, so you want the whole "logic" in oracle  :)

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:130261000346380506

Comment: thanks sir, my answer was same as this but what the problem  I face was i cant perform ON UPDATE cascade therefore if parentTable username updated i want the childTable email_address o update too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you?  Yes.  Should you?  Almost certainly not.

You can [use this AskTom package to generate triggers that implement cascading updates](http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2009/10/httpasktomoraclecomtkyteupdatecascade.html).  That will generate a few triggers and a package and implement the various bits of logic that you'd need to cascade updates.

Functionally, though, that is a lot of moving pieces running in your database in order to implement a cascading update.  Generally, a desire to do cascading updates implies that your choice of primary key is less than ideal.  A primary key ought to be immutable.  In this example, I would strongly prefer that the primary key of `parentTable` be changed to a sequence-generated value that would never change and `username`/ `email` be made `unique`.  The child table could then use the immutable sequence-generated value as the foreign key and users would be free to update their email addresses without needing to cascade the update through the various child tables.